# HTML Hrefs in Tomcat

Tags: html, json, tomcat

I'm building a HTML string in tomcat and I notice that in my JSON object, my clickable href link is something like:

http://localhost/%22/https://myLinkHere.com/%22

This is a 2 part question. First, should it contain the http://localhost in front? And secondly, why is the %22 there?

Here is what my JSON href looks like in text:

```
<a href=\"https:/myLinkHere\">linkDisplayName</a>
```

This looks right to me, but I can't tell why the last %22 is there.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you won't need the localhost as long as you are supplying the relative path
2. The ascii code for %22 is " which is correctly referenced in your link.

Comment: Is there some way I can make my link clickable and it'll go to the right link? For example when I click the link the hyperlink is https://mylinkhere.com instead of http://localhost/%22/https://myLinkHere.com/%22?

Comment: As per my understanding wherever you are adding this info to Json you have extra characters. Make sure you are adding it the correct way. I have done it in the past where I have added the link through Json and it was clickable

Answer (score 0):

HTML parsers are very lenient, which often leads to confusing behavior. Without the exact JSON it's hard to say for sure but there are a couple of obvious issues. Ultimately the issue is your HTML is malformed and/or mis-escaped.

`%22` is `"` [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), which means that the quotes you've `\`-escaped are being included in the URL rather than surrounding them. That likely means that in the JSON they're double-escaped. That might mean it's `\\"` or something similar; try just a single backslash (`\"`) or no backslash at all (`"`).

Notice that the protocol (`https:/`) in your URL is also wrong; a [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) starts with a protocol (like `https`) followed by a `:`, and generally followed by two slashes (`//`). Your URL follows the protocol with just a single slash, which makes it look like a relative URL rather than an absolute one. Browsers will prefix relative URLs with whatever they infer the current host to be, which in your context appears to be `localhost`.

The HTML *should* look like this:

```
<a href="https://myLinkHere">linkDisplayName</a>
```

So in summary no, the URL should probably not contain `http://localhost`, and it should not contain those `%22`s either. They're showing up because your JSON is malformed.